# In unity how to acces transform rotation in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a bouncing and spinning box game. For each spin score will increase.I wrote a code about that but doesn't work. I searched internet but couldn't find answer.

```
GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("Player");
PlayerEverything player1 = thePlayer.GetComponent<PlayerEverything>();
if (!player1.isGrounded)
{
   if(thePlayer.transform.localRotation.z == 0) 
   {
       scorePoint++;
       scoreCombo++;
   }
   if(thePlayer.transform.localRotation.z == 90)
   {
       scorePoint++;
       scoreCombo++;
   }
   if(thePlayer.transform.localRotation.z == 180)
   {
       scorePoint++;
       scoreCombo++;
   }
   if(thePlayer.transform.localRotation.z == -180)
   {
       scorePoint++;
       scoreCombo++;
   }
   if(thePlayer.transform.localRotation.z == -90)
   {
       scorePoint++;
       scoreCombo++;
   }
   scoreCombo = scorePoint;
   score += scorePoint;
}
```

this is my edited code

```
if (!player1.isGrounded)
{
    currentRotation += Vector3.SignedAngle( transform.parent.right,Vector3.up, transform.right);
    if (Mathf.Abs(currentRotation) > 90) 
    {
                
       scorePoint++;
       scoreCombo++;
    }
    Debug.Log("" + currentRotation);
    currentRotation = 0;
}
```

[image: GameImage]

Comment: Anyone knows  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple issues here!

First of all **never** compare two `float` values using `==`! Due to the floating point precision this might fail even e.g. for `5f * 0.2f / 10f == 1f` .. the result might be `0.9999999` or `1.000000001`.

Instead you rather would use a certain range like e.g.

```
if(Mathf.Abs(a-b) <= someThreshold)
```

Unity provides [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

> Compares two floating point values and returns true if they are similar.
>
> Floating point imprecision makes comparing floats using the equals operator inaccurate. For example, (1.0 == 10.0 / 10.0) might not return true every time. `Approximately()` compares two floats and returns true if they are within a small value ([`Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html)) of each other.

so using

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(a-b))
```

basically equals doing

```
if(Mathf.Abs(a-b) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
```

where [`Mathf.Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) is

> The smallest value that a float can have different from zero.

---

Then [`Transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) and [`Transform.localRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html) is a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) which has **four** components `x`, `y`, `z` **and `w`**. Each of these moves in a range `[-1; 1]`. Except you know exactly what you are doing (which you don't ;) ) **never** directly read or write components of a `Quaternion`!

Your checks will simply never be `true`!

---

Instead you should rather work with vectors and check e.g.

```
// for storing the current rotation
private float currentRotation;
// for storing the last right direction
private Vector3 lastRight;

...    

if (!player1.isGrounded)
{
    // add the rotation delta since the last frame
    currentRotation += Vector3.SignedAngle(lastRight, transform.right, transform.forward);

    // if it exceeds +/- 90° 
    if(Mathf.Abs(currentRotation) > 90)
    {
        // get points
        scorePoint++;
        scoreCombo++;

        // and reset the rotation counter
        currentRotation = 0;
    }
}

// Update the last right direction with the current one
lastRight = transform.right;
```

see [`Vector3.SignedAngle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SignedAngle.html)

Comment: Thank you i'm gonna try that that is helpful.

Comment: I edited my code as you can see above. that is works a little.The code is working but it's a bit wrong, what did I do wrong? @derHugo

Comment: I updated the code, my bad ^^ I compared against the wrong value ;) Also you should only reset the `currentRotation = 0;` **inside** the `if` case

Comment: the thing is SignedAngle needs 3 parameters but in your code there is 2 what shold i use for third parameter.I looked unity script reference but it doesn't work. @derHugo

Comment: I'm bookmarking the question so I can this answer as a canonical answer (as you know this question is a very common one in some form or another). Excellent job as usual, derHugo!

Comment: @Ruzihm this answer is under the assumption though that the object actually is always **only** rotated around its `transform.forward` axis ;) otherwise we would always have to map/project the axes accordingly .. and I was just too lazy to do this on the phone for now ^^

Comment: @derHugo i made exactly your code sir but it is still don't work for me. What is the problem my code is your edited code. https://imgur.com/a/GpuEco8

Comment: if (!isGrounded)
        {
            currentRotation += Vector3.SignedAngle(lastRight, transform.right, transform.forward);
            if (Mathf.Abs(currentRotation) > 90)
            {

                

                currentRotation = 0;
            }
            
        }

        lastRight = transform.right;